# Deleted conda environments still appears in jupyter-lab. How can I remove them?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda, environment

Formerly, I add a conda installation of Python in `~/opt/anaconda3` with 3 environments : `DEV (python 3.9)` , `PYT (python 3.11)` and `PROD (python 3.10)`

I removed it (all `~/opt` deleted), an now I have a miniconda installation in `~/miniconda3`, with one environment : `PROD (python 3.10)`

When I start `jupyter-lab`, it still offers me to create notebook with `DEV`, `PYT` and `PROD`. It evidently fails if I try to use one of the two firsts, saying that  `~/opt/anaconda3/envs/DEV` does not exists.

How can I get rid of the two inexistent environments ? Where is the memory of that ?

Computer is Mac under OSX 13.2.1. jupyter-lab is 3.6.3.

Thanks,

Olivier

Answer (score 5):

Did you look at your ~/.bashrc file, which might still export the path of those environments in your python path?

Using the command `jupyter kernelspec list`, you can look at the different envs you created. If you see unwanted kernels, you can do `jupyter kernelspec uninstall unwanted-kernel`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the envs in `~/Library/Jupyter/kernels`

@CamB04 : I found my solution without kernelspec. But yes, I see now that `jupyter kernelspec ...` is the right tool. Thank :-)